HALCON + C# - How can show selected objects with Halcon procedure in WinForms program?
I'm trying to create a WinForms program that shows the result of Halcon procedure. This procedure (for now) is a variation of detect_mura_defects_texture, which I have adapted to become a hdvp.
The point is that I d'ont know how to show the defects selected by the select_mask_obj function. At the moment, my Halcon procedure is:
decompose3(Image, R, G, B)
get_image_size(B, Width, Height)
rft_generic(B, ImageFFT, 'to_freq', 'none', 'complex', Width)
gen_gauss_filter(ImageGauss, 50, 50, 0, 'n', 'rft', Width, Height)
convol_fft(ImageFFT,  ImageGauss, ImageConvol)
rft_generic(ImageConvol, IlluminationImage, 'from_freq', 'none', 'byte', Width)
sub_image(B, IlluminationImage, ImageSub, 2, 100)
median_image(ImageSub, ImageMedian, 'circle', 9, 'mirrored')
watersheds_threshold(ImageMedian, Basins, 20)
cooc_feature_image(Basins, ImageMedian, 6, 0, Energy, Correlation, Homogeneity, Contrast)
Mask := Energy [<=] 0.05
select_mask_obj(Basins, Defects, Mask)
dev_open_window(0, 0, 640, 480, 'green', WindowHandle)
dev_display(Image)
dev_display(Defects)
return ()

In my WinForms application, I can execute the Halcon procedure and shows the result in a ´Halcon.DotNet.HWindowControl´ (I have tried it with other Halcon procedures that return an image), but I don't know how to get the "Defects" that this scripts calculates and display it in hWindowControl1.
private void ImageJoinBtn_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string procedureName = selectHalconProcedure.Text;

    switch (procedureName.Split(' ')[0]) {

        case "0":
            JoinTwoImagesProcedure();
            break;

        case "1":
            GetDefectsProcedure();
            break;

    }

}

private void GetDefectsProcedure () {

    try {

        ING_Halcon halconScript = new ING_Halcon(HALCON_SCRIPTS_LIST[SCRIPT_TWO]);
        halconScript.SetInputImage("Image", img1HParam);
        halconScript.Execute();
        var defects = halconScript.GetParamTupleImage("Defects");
        HWindow hWin = hWindowControl1.HalconWindow;
        HImage result = img1HParam;
        hWin.DispImage(result);
        hWin.DispObj(defects); // TODO: this instruction do nothing.

    }

    catch (Exception exc) {

        Console.WriteLine($"GetDefectsProcedure Exception:\n\t{exc}.");

    }

}

Thanks for your help

Really, the solution is very simple. My HWindow control "hwin" was not programmed to zoom in or zoom out. I couldn't drag the image either, which looked zoomed in too much. To solve this, just change the tool window "HWindowControl" by "HSmartWindowControl". You also need to schedule the "´Load´" event as follows.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    hWin = hSmartWindowControl1.HalconWindow; // "hWin" has a private variable now.
    hSmartWindowControl1.MouseWheel += hSmartWindowControl1.HSmartWindowControl_MouseWheel;

}

Is possible that the elements obtained by function hWin.DispObj(...) may appear white on agrayscale image, so they may not stand out much in your application. Is possible to change it adding:
hWin.SetColor("green");
hWin.SetLineWidth(5);

Reference: SetColor and SetLineWidth.
